# How do I strip all letters, whitespaces and empty lines from a txt file and write to excel

Tags: python

I have a file like this

```
 cat

123-1
 2311
```

I want it to be like this with no leading or trailing white spaces
or empty lines

```
123-1
2311
```

```py
with open(r"C:\Users\mike\test.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    readline= f.readlines()


#clearUnwantedCharacters= ''.join(filter(clearlist.__contains__,readline))
#readline= ''.join(filter(clearlist.__contains__,readline))


readline =[line.replace(' ', '') for line in readline]

#readline =[line.replace('\n', '') for line in readline]

#######
lines= readline.split("\n")

no_empty_string= [line for line in lines if line.strip() !=" "]

'''
since list cannot be split, split individual items on the list  and append 

'''

readline =""

for line in no_empty_string:
    readline += line + "\n"


######

#test= readline

#remove unwanted characters with regex 
# readline= re.sub('[^0-9]',' ', str(readline))

# readline.strip(' ')

print(readline)
with open(r"C:\Users\mike\test.txt", 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.writelines(readline)
```

But I don't get the desired result ( i.e not been able to clean the list of white spaces and letters)

-- updating question with more information, i would like to write the text to excel, so instead of a newline, comma separated lines would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Opening both files, iterating over the lines using .strip()
# and saving only lines that are not empty.
with open('test.txt', "r") as original, open("new_file.txt", "w") as new_file:
    for line in original:
        sline = line.strip()
        if line not in ('', '\n'):
            new_file.write(sline + "\n")
```

```sh
$ cat new_file.txt 
123-1
2311
```

Comment: Nice. Could you [edit] and explain the code a bit? Code-only answers tend to get flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @Robert, for sure I would, but there is not much to explain.

Comment: Thanks. It may be easy for you, but maybe not so much for Python newbies, that's why I asked. If you post only code, people may or may not understand it and just copy & paste from the web.

Comment: @ArthurHarduim this does not remove the letters and thus is not the right answer

Comment: @rizu, wich letters?

Comment: @ArthurHarduim ``cat``,   i put it in the question, this can also be random letters "a-z", i want only numbers  and all letters (character strings) should be removed

Comment: @rizu. There is a unix command utility call 'cat', I was under the impression that your 'cat' was that command, but now I see it isn't.